# tslearn How to extract the elements from the species cluster by TSLEARN

Tags: python

I am a beginner of XX.I use tslearn time cluster, I completed the clustering based on documentation, but I don't know how to extract the elements in the cluster, tslearn data format requirements are three-dimensional array (n, sz, dimenation), and there can be a string, I see fit to predict function, it told me to return to the Index of the cluster each sample belongs to. But I do not understand the output results.I would like to consult you.Because the data format cannot contain strings, I also thought about using a 4-dimensional array to label, but the TXT made according to the format requirements does not seem to be able to achieve this function.Now I have a 120-country, 9-day, 1-dimensional data, code data set and running results shown hereenter image description here[enter image description here][enter image description here]2enter image description here

```
from tslearn.utils import save_time_series_txt, load_time_series_txt
import numpy as np
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from tslearn.clustering import KShape
from tslearn.datasets import CachedDatasets
from tslearn.preprocessing import TimeSeriesScalerMeanVariance
from tslearn.clustering import GlobalAlignmentKernelKMeans
from tslearn.metrics import sigma_gak
from tslearn.clustering import TimeSeriesKMeans
time_series_dataset = load_time_series_txt("monday - 副本.txt")
X_train=time_series_dataset
X_train.shape
#np.random.shuffle(X_train)
# For this method to operate properly, prior scaling is required
#seed = 0
#numpy.random.seed(seed)
sz = X_train.shape[1]
# DBA-k-means
print("DBA k-means")
dba_km = TimeSeriesKMeans(n_clusters=3,
                          n_init=2,
                          metric="dtw",
                          verbose=True,
                          max_iter_barycenter=10)
y_pred = dba_km.fit_predict(X_train)
for yi in range(3):
    #plt.subplot(3, 3, 4 + yi)
    for xx in X_train[y_pred == yi]:
        plt.plot(xx.ravel(), "k-", alpha=.2)
    plt.plot(dba_km.cluster_centers_[yi].ravel(), "-")
    plt.xlim(0, sz)
    #plt.ylim(-1.2,1.5)
    plt.text(0.55, 0.85,'Cluster %d' % (yi + 1),
             transform=plt.gca().transAxes)
    if yi == 1:
        plt.title("DBA $k$-means")

plt.figure()
for yi in range(3):
    #plt.subplot(4, 1, 1 + yi)
    #for xx in X_train[y_pred == yi]:
        #plt.plot(xx.ravel(), "k-", alpha=.2)
    plt.plot(dba_km.cluster_centers_[yi].ravel(), "-")
    plt.xlim(0, sz)
    #plt.ylim(-1.2,1.5)
    plt.title("Cluster %d" % (yi + 1))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

for yi in range(3):
    #plt.subplot(3, 3, 4 + yi)
    #for xx in X_train[y_pred == yi]:
        #plt.plot(xx.ravel(), "k-", alpha=.2)
    plt.plot(dba_km.cluster_centers_[yi].ravel(), "-")
```

Comment: It seems that I can't send my data in this page.If you can help me ,please contact at daibitao@nudt.edu.cn  so that I can send my data to you.Thanks a lot

Comment: Suggest you add the tag 'time-series' which will highlight your question to those familiar with the domain.